# Печать строки в зависимости от содержимого и подстановка параметров в алиас

Tags: bash

Нашел команду которая печатает логи апача с поддержкой юникода:

```
tailf /var/log/apache2/error.log | while read -r line; do echo -e "$line"; done;
```

Хочу сделать алиас на нее, например utail, который будет принимать один обязательный параметр - файл и второй не обязательный - искомая строка.
Пример вызова:

```
utail /var/log/apache2/error.log "/api/v0.1"
```

Найденная строка должна целиком или частично иметь желтый фон \033[43m "$line "\033[0m (Если такое возможно и будет работать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте функцию:

```
utail() {
#Первый параметр обязательный
    file="${1:?Не передано имя файла}"
#Второй параметр строка поиска
    searchLine="${2}"
#Проверка существует ли файл, если нет, возникнет ошибка
    [[ -f "${file}" ]] || { echo "файл ${file} не существует"; return 1; }
#Начало цикла
    while read -r line; do
#Проверка, если переменная строки поиска не пустая, 
#и строка содержит искомый текс =~, либо равна ==, нужное подставить
        if [[ -n "${searchLine:+123}" && "${line}" =~ "${searchLine}" ]]; then
#То печатаем с подсветкой
            echo -e "\033[43m${line}\033[0m"
        else
#Иначе без подсветки
            echo -e "${line}"
        fi
#Передача в цикл файла, отредактировал согласно комментария:
    done< <(tail -F "${file}")
}
```

И запускайте функцию так же:

```
utail "/file" "line"
```

Функцию так же можно добавить в **bashrc** как глобально для всех пользователей, так и одного пользователя

Comment: Достигает конца файла и выходит из функции, а tailf читает файл потоково и не выходит...

Comment: done < <(tailf "{$file}") решил проблему

Answer (score 0):

```
utail(){awk -v l="$2" '$0~l{$0="\033[43m"$0"\033[0m"}{print}' "$1"}
```